# How to set the next action's parameter in charm layer code

Tags: juju

I develop a juju charm reactive layer_A with action_A. In the charm I have included another layer_B, which contains action_B.

I want to trigger action_B in action_A code. When I set flag `action_B.run` in the last line of action_A code, it works. But I must set action_B parameters passed through CLI:

```
juju run-action <unit_name> action_A <action_B parameters>
```

I want to know how to set action_B parameters in the code of action_A. In this way I can trigger action_B through

```
juju run-action <unit_name> action_A <action_A parameters>
```

Comment: Sorry. There are some mistake. right is: ...But I must to set action_B parameters pass through cli 'juju run-action action_A <action_B param>'. I want to know how to set action_B parameters in the code of action_A. In this way I can trigger action_B through 'juju run-action action_A <action_A param>'

Comment: Please [edit] your question whenever you need to correct the post or add new information. Do not use comments for that.